# How to quickly transfer text multiple times from Android to Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, transfer

I would like to move quickly and painlessly text over my phone to Ubuntu to just use it as i need to, any way of doing so Is appreciated! Thanks! (Im on 22.04)

Comment: Could you update your question and define "painlessly" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several WhatsApp clients for Ubuntu in the Snap Store, for example whatsapp-for-linux, an unofficial WhatsApp desktop application for Linux. To install it run `sudo snap install whatsapp-for-linux`

To print a list of WhatsApp snap packages run `snap find whatsapp`